# Configure a symfony database connection from ini file?

Tags: symfony, symfony-config-component

On the server I need to deploy my symfony 5.2.4 application, the database configuration is defined in an ini file for which the path is set as an environment variable.

The way I have done it right now is to run `composer dump-env dev` then in `.env.local.php`, add some code to load the inifile, parse it, then construct my database url and set DATABASE_URL to that value like that:

```php
$inifile = parse_ini_file($_SERVER["DB_INI_PATH"]);
$databaseurl = 'mysql://'.$inifile["user"].':'.$inifile["password"].'@'.$inifile["host"].':'.$inifile["port"].'/'.$inifile["db"];
```

But this means that I have some code in this file that can't be versioned (because it also contains my APP_SECRET value), and anytime I need to redump my env, I will need to readd that custom code.

I have not found a proper place to add this ini file decoding process in my symfony app, so I am looking for any advice on the proper way to do that, in a way that would be versionable.

Comment: Please, don't add answers inside your question. If the Arleigh's anwser is not complete (is not a comment), invite him to complete it, otherwise you can add your solution in the answer section and retract your vote to the Arleight's answer to then mark your own as accepted.

Comment: thanks @gp_sflover I didn't know this, I will comment on Arleigh's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your doctrine config in php and you will have access to environment variables. You can add your logic in "config/packages/prod/doctrine.php". The example in the docs shows how to set `doctrine.dbal.url` go here and click on the php tab for the example code: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-based-on-environment-variables

Comment: Thanks Arleigh, I had tried replacing the services.yaml to services.php but didn't find that it was possible de do it for doctrine.yaml.

Comment: To complete this answer, one needs to add to config/services.yaml the following lines in case you can to keep default config in doctrine.yaml + use doctrine.php just for the url part. At least this is what I have been obliged to add, otherwise doctrine.php would not load, and I didn't want to rewrite all the doctrine.yaml into doctrine.php.

imports:
    - { resource: 'packages/doctrine.php' }